# How do I create my own unitary matrices that I can apply to a circuit in Cirq?

Tags: cirq

I am trying to simulate Deutsch's algorithm, and I need to apply the oracle function matrix to my circuit.

Answer (score 3):

[Note: this answer is outdated]

This is going to change somewhat radically in the next version of cirq, so I'll give an answer for both versions.

In v0.3, in order for a simulator to understand a custom gate, the gate must implement either `cirq.CompositeGate` or `cirq.KnownMatrix`. For your case, the simplest is to implement the matrix:

```
# assuming cirq v0.3
import cirq
import numpy as np
class Oracle(cirq.Gate, cirq.KnownMatrix):
    def __init__(self, secret_state, qubit_count):
        self.secret_state = secret_state
        self.qubit_count = qubit_count
    def matrix(self):
        m = np.eye(1 << self.qubit_count)
        m[self.secret_state, self.secret_state] = -1
        return m
```

You can then use this oracle to simulate e.g. a Grover circuit and see that the secret state ends up with quite a high probability:

```
qs = cirq.LineQubit.range(5)
secret = 5
oracle = Oracle(secret, len(qs)).on(*qs)

diffusion = [
    cirq.H.on_each(qs),
    Oracle(0, len(qs)).on(*qs),
    cirq.H.on_each(qs)
]
c = cirq.Circuit.from_ops(
    cirq.H.on_each(qs),
    [oracle, diffusion] * 4
)
output_vector = c.apply_unitary_effect_to_state()
print(np.round(abs(output_vector)**2, 3))
# [0  0  0  0  0  .999  0  0 ...]
#                  ^ big probability at offset 5
```

In the coming v0.4 the classes such as `KnownMatrix` will be replaced by "magic methods" such as `_unitary_`. (This is generally how things are supposed to be done in python.) One of those magic methods is `_apply_unitary_to_tensor_`, which is used to enable faster simulation. With that method the oracle application can be simulated much much faster; in $O(q)$ time instead of $O(4^q)$ time assuming the oracle covers all of the qubits. We also happen to avoid the need to know the number of qubits ahead of time:

```
# assuming cirq v0.4
import cirq
class Oracle(cirq.Gate):
    def __init__(self, secret_state):
        self.secret_state = secret_state
    def _apply_unitary_to_tensor_(self, target_tensor, available_buffer, axes):
        s = cirq.slice_for_qubits_equal_to(axes, self.secret_state)
        target_tensor[s] *= -1
        return target_tensor
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched for doing a custom gate on the Cirq documentation and here are the  [results](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simulation.html?highlight=Custom%20gate) :

> Gate sets
>
> The xmon simulator is designed to work with operations that
> are either a GateOperation applying an XmonGate, a CompositeOperation
> that decomposes (recursively) to XmonGates, or a 1-qubit or 2-qubit
> operation with a KnownMatrix. By default the xmon simulator uses an
> Extension defined in xgate_gate_extensions to try to resolve gates
> that are not XmonGates to XmonGates.
>
> So if you are using a custom gate, there are multiple options for
> getting it to work with the simulator:
>
> Define it directly as an XmonGate. Provide a CompositeGate made up of
> XmonGates. Supply an Exentension to the simulator which converts the
> gate to an XmonGate or to a CompositeGate which itself can be
> decomposed in XmonGates.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem outdated, so here is an answer written for Cirq v0.7.0. Applying a unitary matrix is basically constructing a custom gate, and a simple example for a qubit is shown below. The gate below simply converts `0 -> 1` and `1 -> 0`, but more complex examples are possible.

```
import cirq
import numpy as np

class QubitPlusGate(cirq.SingleQubitGate):
    def _unitary_(self):
        # Our input is q = a[0] + b[1]
        # And our output becomes q = b[0] + a[1]
        return np.array([[0, 1],
                         [1, 0]])

    def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args):
        return '[+1]'

# Create a single line qubit
q0 = cirq.GridQubit(0, 0)

circuit = cirq.Circuit(
    QubitPlusGate().on(q0),
    cirq.measure(q0)
)

# Simulate the circuit several times.
simulator = cirq.Simulator()
result = simulator.run(circuit, repetitions=10)
print("Results:")
print(result)
```

If you want to view more complex examples, it is best to dive into the [source code](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/cirq/ops/common_gates.py) of some gates supplied by cirq itself, but the implementation architecture is exactly the same.